# Add roster from another domain to openfire

Tags: openfire

I am trying to figure out how to add a roster of users to my openfire server that are on another domain. Essentially just a bunch of contacts, not user accounts that I can login with. What I would like to do is have that group of users auto-populate in the contacts area of our xmpp client. I have our domain users auto populating with no issues, however, there is another domain with users that we would like to have auto populate as well. Is there a way of doing this? The other domain is using a Cisco XMPP implementation, which makes it all the more "fun" lol. Thanks for the help.

Jon

Comment: Just out of curiosity, will the users of other domains be able to receive the presence subscription notifications (as they are using XMPP)? if not, what is the motivation of adding the other domain rosters?

Comment: Really it's because the users are whiny b*tches and they want to see the names auto-populate, and they seem to think I have nothing better to do with my life than to fix this one problem for them - but I can't tell them that, because the truth hurts their sensibilities...

From the tech standpoint though, I would like to see if I can make it happen. I tried adding a contact in AD, but that didn't work either. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated though.